# Does AlamoFire use a singleton to abstract it's client class?

Tags: swift, singleton, alamofire, static-methods

I'm asking because there is no `sharedInstance` call.

I took a look at the source code but I couldn't figure out exactly what was going on. 
They seem to be calling methods on a type `Alamofire`, are they using static methods ?

Example from their Github `README.md` file:

`Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get")`

---

I'm currenly using singletons for my client classes because clients are expensive. 
But the method calls are very long.

`MyClient.sharedInstance.myMethod(withParameter:"000")`

How does AlamoFire deal with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alamofire.request calls SessionManager.default.request

SessionManager.default is a singleton

You can add same methods to your MyClient

```
extension MyClient{
    static func myMethod(withParameter:String){
        sharedInstance.myMethod(withParameter:withParameter)
    }
}
```

Comment: That works nicely. myMethod can be called in two diffrent ways, is that default behavior ?

Comment: wouldn't this defeat the purpose of a singleton ? In other words should they have just used class methods in the first place ?

Comment: 1) you can make your sharedInstance private or fileprivate  
2)I don't know why they did this.